# How to make inline-block align right

Tags: html, css, flexbox, text-align

I am trying to align an image to the right but haven't been able to do so despite repeated attempts using flex, text-align etc.

I have already looked through many questions but didn't find a satisfactory answer.

```css
img {
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: right;
    }
```

```html
<h1>
  <img src="burj.jpeg">    
  Enjoy the world of pure travel masti
</h1>
```

Comment: use `float:right` , instead of `text-align:right`.

Comment: You could better place the image tag after the text, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Placing `h1` image tag after the text would serve the purpose.

```
<h1>  
      Enjoy the world of pure travel masti
      <img src="burj.jpeg" alt="Sample Picture">  
 </h1>
```

Comment: Wow!! What A Stupid Mistake! :p :)

Answer (score 0):

you could use float right

```css
img {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<h1>
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">    
        Enjoy the world of pure travel masti
    </h1>
CSS:-
```

---

**Edition**

```css
img {
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<h1>
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">    
        Enjoy the world of pure travel masti
    </h1>
CSS:-
```

Comment: I already tried using <code>float:right</code> but It doesn't work for me.

Comment: that is the left side just add float left

Comment: @RohitKumar, you have no idea , what is left and what is right ?

Comment: I want it on right --> the direction in which this --> arrow is pointing

Comment: @KetanModi I think u r confused

Comment: I think there is some writing direction confusion. Did you set `direction: rtl;` somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `img` (=element name) instead of `.img` (=class name) and then use `float`:

```
img {
    display: inline-block;
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: Sorry it was a typo in the question.

Answer (score 0):

> You are using `.` operator in CSS while `img` is the tag name.
>   `.` operator is used in the class name while `#` operator in `id`. Direct tag nme is used while eriting their CSS.

Write this.

```
img {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}
```

Run it [here](https://codepen.io/sirajalam049/pen/ZaxObO).